# Insight (gdb) debugger problem while debugging 32 bit binary on 64 bit machine

Tags: gdb

I am creating 32-bit binary on 64-bit machine using '-m32' option of gcc. When I debug that binary on 64-bit machine then after certain amount of code, If I step-in to some function, it takes me to different function. I think function stack code segment generated wrong somewhere?
Please help if anyone knows the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you disable optimizations (usually `-O2` flag) when you built your 32-bit binary?

> I think function stack code segment generated wrong somewhere?

There is no such thing as 'stack code segment'. That combination of words makes no sense whatsoever.

In any case, debugging 32-bit binary with 64-bit GDB on Linux just works (TM), and is unlikely to have anything to do with your problem.

Comment: Hi, I am not using optimizations while compiling sources. I am still facing same problem.